# Middleman - How to change the paths for generated html files?

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm building a website using Middleman. There are source files placed like the following.

```
source/index.html.md
source/errors/404.html
source/docs/foo.html.md
source/docs/bar.html.md
```

By default, when I build static html files, the generated files are placed following to the original directory structure (with directory indexes).

```
build/index.html
build/errors/404/index.html
build/docs/foo/index.html
build/docs/bar/index.html
```

However, I want all html files to be served directly under `/`, so that they can be accessed like `http://example.com/foo/` and `http://example.com/404/`.

How do you change the paths for generated html files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use proxies to create duplicate pages, and then ignore the original pages.

https://middlemanapp.com/basics/dynamic-pages/

But the simplest way is, of course, to adjust the source structure to match the desired structure.

Comment: This will not work when you want to overwrite the index.html files with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/pretty-urls/) part of Middleman doc could help you .
All you need is to activate directory indexes and configure it properly, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, but "directory indexes" itself is not the point in this case. I want to change the paths for generated html files from the original directory tree structure.